# dynamically output YAML list in a Ansible Task

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a way to dynamically output YAML list in a Ansible Task.
I've looking at Jinja templating, but AFAIK it creates files to deploy.
So my use case is:
ensure one or multiple triggers on a `win_sched_task` based on a variable containing a list of `triggers`

```
# main.yaml
- name: Create task with multiple triggers
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: TriggerTask
    path: \Custom
    actions:
    - path: cmd.exe
    triggers:
    {{ list_triggers }}
    username: SYSTEM
```

where `list_triggers` is a list containing one or multiple triggers of that task:

```
# vars.yaml
list_triggers:
- type: daily
  start_boundary: '2020-04-28T09:00:00'
- type: daily
  start_boundary: '2020-04-28T19:00:00'
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
- name: Create task with multiple triggers
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: TriggerTask
    path: \Custom
    actions:
    - path: cmd.exe
    triggers:
    - type: daily
      start_boundary: '2020-04-28T09:00:00'
    - type: daily
      start_boundary: '2020-04-28T19:00:00'
    username: SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was overthinking it. It worked with this:
triggers: "{{ list_triggers }}"